# Is there such thing as a software switchboard for Trixbox/freepbx/asterisk?

Tags: linux, voip, telephony, asterisk

We use Trixbox CE and would like something so that we can load a window that tells us which lines are in use around the office. Currently no need to use it to actually make calls or anything, but just view who is on their phone and who is not.

There are hardware versions of this like: [image]

We just want a software version that you could open on a secondary monitor.

Comment: A quick search reveals a lot of options, especially paid corporate options that might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of different options.  Here are a few examples:

- [Flash Operator Panel 2](http://www.fop2.com/)
- [Noojee Receptionist](http://noojee.com.au/products/noojee-receptionist/receptionist-overview/)
- [iSymphony](http://www.i9technologies.com/content/view/19/40/)

Comment: We went with FOP 2 as you mention here. It gives the basic functions and is very cheap and easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer free solutions there's always [MonAst](http://monast.sourceforge.net/).

> Monast is a monitoring interface which acts as an operator panel for Asterisk™.
>
> What Monast can display (in realtime)?
>
> - Multiple Servers
> - Users and Peers (SIP, IAX, DAHDI, Khomp, etc...)
> - Channels and Calls (with channel name and callerid)
> - Meetmes (with connected users)
> - Parked Calls
> - Queues (with all statistics, members and waiting clients)